# API com Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Gostaria de saber como faço para fazer uma API na linguagem javascript para retornar dados como JSON. Estou precisando pois quero fazer um aplicativo mobile.

Comment: Como são os dados que você quer retornar como JSON?

Comment: por exemplo, quero criar uma url que retorna um conjunto de objetos, por exemplo, 
"http://exemploapi.com/clientes"
retorno = {"id":"1", "status": "0", "erro":"","mensagem":"Teste"}

Comment: Você está usando JS no servidor, certo? Node.js?

Comment: Sim. Vou usar Node.JS no servidor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma e fazer uma API é criando um arquivo JavaScript separado contendo um ou vários objetos declarando as funções que você precisa em sua API.

Por exemplo, segue abaixo uma API fictícia representando uma calculadora simples:

```
// calculadora. js
var calculadora = {
    somar: function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    },

    multiplicar: function (a, b) {
        return a * b;
    }
};
```

Para usar sua API você primeiro precisa importar o arquivo JavaScript da API na página por meio de uma tag script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pasta_da_api/calculadora.js" />
```

Feito isso, você agora pode chamar os métodos declarados em sua API assim:

```
var soma = calculadora.somar(a, b);

var produto = calculadora.multiplicar(a, b);
```

Comment: E onde entra o JSON?

Comment: A própria API nesse exemplo que eu dei é um objeto JSON. Você pode retornar qualquer coisa nos métodos de sua api, inclusive um json. Vou editar a resposta adicionando um novo método que retorna um JSON para servir como exemplo.

Comment: Quero retornar esses dados via url: exemplo de url: http://interatividade.globo.com/notas/agregador/torcidometro_14417/resultado-estrutura-resumido.json

Comment: Então no caso o que você precisa é de um Webservice, e não uma API JavaScript. Mas pela sua pergunta deu a entender o que eu respondi, que você queria criar uma API em JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm, desculpe se eu falei errado, vocês conhecem algum link que esteja explicando algo sobre webservices?

Comment: Mas faz assim, Danilo. Cria outra pergunta, por que essa aqui também vai ser útil para a comunidade. Na nova pergunta você informa que precisa de um Webservice que retorne dados em formato JSON. Existem muitas opções, e praticamente qualquer tecnologia de backend oferece esse recurso. Por ser programador .NET eu uso o ServiceStack. Pode ser uma boa opção para você também se você programa em alguma linguagem .NET.

Comment: Ulysses, esse seu código não é um "objeto JSON", é JavaScript. JSON são objetos serializados (como strings), e o formato não aceita funções. Esse seu código nunca poderia ser serializado (mas os retornos das funções poderiam).

Comment: @bfavaretto creio que você está equivocado em alguns pontos. JSONs e strings são suas coisas diferentes. Por exemplo, o JSON **{nome: "João", idade: 13}** pode set convertido para string por meio do método JSON.stringfy, o que iria retornar a string **'{"nome": "João", "idade": 13}'**. E para converter de string para JSON tem o método JSON.parse. logo, strings e JSONs são coisas diferentes, ou seja, são formas diferentes de representar a mesma informação. Portanto meu objeto é de fato um JSON.

Comment: Não Ulysses, você está confundindo objetos literais do JavaScript com JSON. Essa confusão é bastante comum, já que eles são bastante parecidos. O JSON é baseado nos literais do JS – inclusive o "JS" em "JSON" quer dizer JavaScript. O JSON é um formato de troca de dados entre sistemas ou máquinas, que aceita um conjunto limitado de tipos (e funções não são aceitas em JSON), com [regras](http://json.org/) bem claras de representação (como aspas nas chaves, opcionais nos literais do JS). Os métodos JS que você citou convertem de JSON para valores/objetos, e de valores/objetos para JSON.